# How do I configure wpa_supplicant.conf for WPS push-button?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

I'm building an IOT device, powered by headless Debain on a CHIP (https://getchip.com/), and will have connectivity to a customer's wifi.  I'm trying to build in functionality for wifi connectivity to the customer's router in a way that wouldn't require the customer to ever need to input a password and username.  Basically, I'd like to have WPS push-button functionality in Unix.

I've installed `wpa_cli`, and have been tinkering around with wpa_supplicant.conf.  However I'm very confused.  The example `.conf` document located [here](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf) , states that we'd need to input all the parameters of the router ahead of time.  Why would that ever need to be the case?  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of WPS (i.e. WPS should be blind to any access points and should handshake with the nearest router that has its WPS window open)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` configuration file as follow:

At least you need to add the following line :

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1
CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
```

You can enable some others support:

```
 ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
 ctrl_interface_group=0
 update_config=1
 CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
 CONFIG_WPS=y
 CONFIG_WPS2=y
 CONFIG_WPS_ER=y
 CONFIG_WPS_NFC=y
 uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Get the `uuid` through `status` command from `wpa_cli`

To connect

1. run `wpa_cli`
2. From the Interactive mode, run `wps_pbc` and  push the `wps` button.
3. Once connected run `dhclient wlan0` (change `wlan0` with your interface wifi)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to come back to this; urgent things came up.  This worked perfectly!  You showed me the final step that I was missing: the dhclient.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation at [w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README-WPS).

The documentation you were looking at shows all the possible options in `wpa_supplicant.conf`, which includes options for static configuration.

You also need to write a script so that when the WPS button on your device is pressed then you execute `wpa_cli wps_pbc` to alert wpa_supplicant.  It's also a good idea to capture a multisecond key-press and use that to reset wpa_supplicant's configuration (allowing the user to move your device).

Comment: That's a great piece of advice about the button to reset the supplicant.  Thanks!