# Is it possible to detect if a Router WPS button has been pressed or not by just passively monitoring traffic?

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wireshark, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng, wps

I mean you could check if the wps button has been pressed or not using this command

> [wpa_cli wps_pbc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310764)

But i am wondering if it's possible to do it using airodump-ng

Without any one connecting to it.

The [wifiphisher Utility](https://github.com/wifiphisher/wifiphisher/blob/master/wifiphisher/extensions/wpspbc.py) claims to be able to do it , even that i wasn't able to find any info about a ready tool that does that

and the python code isn't clear enough so i can't tell how they do it

Trying to figure out a method to do it passively to add it to a possibly new attack vector

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We first check [the Wi-Fi Protected Setup Specification](http://cfile28.uf.tistory.com/attach/16132E3C50FCFFCB3EC74E)

> The AP informs Enrollees that the Selected Registrar is in PBC mode
> using Probe Response messages
>
> The Enrollee performs this scan by sending out probe requests with a
> Device Password ID indicating that the Enrollee is in PBC mode and
> receiving probe responses indicating a Selected Registrar with a PBC
> Device Password ID.
>
> When an AP receives a Selected Registrar and Device Password ID
> indicating PBC mode from a Registrar, it MUST automatically remove
> this information and no longer include it in probe responses after an
> interval of Walk Time has elapsed.Before the Registrar’s button is pushed, the AP shall not advertise any active PBC state

[image]

[image]

[image]

And from another [WPS documentation titled : Wireless LAN PCI Card User Manual V1.1](https://www.192-168-1-1-ip.co/manuals/15531.pdf) We find

> Device Password ID : Indicate the method or identifies the specific
> password that the selected Registrar intends to use. AP in PBC mode
> must indicate 0x0004 within two-minute Walk Time.

We now understand that the info needed are in the beacon Frame that comes from the AP

To check these info we can do this using three tools if you want

First we Check what's the different in the broadcasted probes on a An AP without the button pushed and with the button pushed

To do that we have to use airodump or `tcpdump` twice on the wanted device once with the button pushed and once without it pushed and then we try [the WPS PBC filters from the wireshark wiki](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wps.html) TO find the difference between the two

As we can see here when try any of these filters

```
wps.selected_registrar_config_methods.phy_pushbutton
wps.selected_registrar_config_methods.pushbutton
wps.selected_registrar_config_methods
wps.device_password_id
```

Only the capture with the wps button pushed
Gets matches

[image]

Please Note That Only `wps.device_password_id == 0x0004` filter is   reliable to Check if the Button was pushed or not
as the other filters may result in false positive

An quote From An expert on the matter

> `"wps_selected_registrar" : 01` does not mean all routers are in PBC
> mode, some routers also have `"wps_selected_registrar" : 01` in PIN
> mode, and these routers, 95% or more are vulnerable to Pixie Dust
> attack,

Now that we know and tested the difference.
We can do it using two other tools to take less time

1. We can use this little python scapy script from github [wps2key.py](https://github.com/Tourountzis/wifi-pwn/blob/master/wps2key.py) but note that it works on older systems with 2.7 only

   chmod +x wps2key.py

   ./wps2key.py -i mon0 -v

we can see the difference here too
[image]

2. using the famous tool wash. make sure that it's updated to the latest version from [reaver-wps-fork-t6x](https://github.com/t6x/reaver-wps-fork-t6x) , to see the values we need to use the json option -j. additionally, the json mode detects when the WPS configuration of an already printed AP changes, and prints another line so there is no need for exiting and restarting or a loop to check for changed each time

   wash -i wlan0mon -j

[image]

We can here see the difference too but since wash doesn't show all the other Elements that we have used in wireshark.
we have `wps_device_password_id` or `selected_registrar_config_methods` to Differentiates between pushed and not pushed

Note that we didn't use `wps_selected_registrar` Because it's not reliable

We can also automate it using a one liner
and we will use `-c` and `-b` options to make it faster

```
timeout 10s wash -i wlan0mon -j -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -c 8 | grep -q '"wps_device_password_id" : "0004"' && echo Pushed || echo NotPushed
```

It can also be done using a little python script file

```
import subprocess, sys ,os
argv = list(sys.argv)
argv[0] = 'wash'
proc = subprocess.Popen(argv, executable=argv[0], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while 1:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line == '': break
        print line
        if '"wps_device_password_id" : "0004"' in line:
            proc.terminate()
                print("WPS PBC enabled")
                break
```

Note here To run it

> save the script as washwrapper.py and run it instead of wash with all
> arguments you'd usually pass to wash. like python2 washwrapper.py -j
> -i wlan0mon -c 6 .modify the path to the "../src/wash" wash binary Location instead of just wash , IF needed or it doesn't work

Thanks to u/[rofl0r](https://github.com/rofl0r) for the script and helping on the matter

And if you want to connect to it if we found the button was pushed we can use [wpa_cli wps_pbc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310752/how-do-i-configure-wpa-supplicant-conf-for-wps-push-button/310817#310817) command instead of print
Or better we can use [OneShot](https://github.com/drygdryg/OneShot) Python Script with the new added --pbc flag to do the process in just one click with no Prior configuration And as a bonus it outputs the password too.

> ```
> Start WPS push button connection:
>
> sudo python3 oneshot.py -i wlan0mon --pbc
> ```

[image]

But remember to be able run a system command in python we use
os.system("command")

Finally , I had to Answer this my self after searching the whole web and found Zero sites mentioning or talking about it.